# Google Map V3 Grey Tiles Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps V3, everything is working great, expect the grey tile problem and I do not know how to fix it, I also tried

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

but it didn't work or I pasted it wrong.

Grey Tiles are appearing when I try to move the map, only map window with the width and height is rendered, the rest is grey, when I am using percent the whole map is grey, how can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var styleArray = [{
            "featureType": "administrative.locality",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#365B6A"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "labels.text",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "on"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "geometry.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#c4d3dc"
            }, {
                "weight": 0.1
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
            "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }]
        },

            {
                "featureType": "landscape.natural",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                }, {
                    "color": "#e1e9ee"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit.station",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#cfc824"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#cfc824"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#4d6d7a"
                }, {
                    "weight": 0.5
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#4d6d7a"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.local",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#4d6d7a"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#385c6b"
                }]
            }];


        var submoem = '/media/image/marker.png';
        var primarymoem = '/media/image/marker-main.png';

        var geocoder;
        var markersArray = [];

        var locationsArray = [
            '{$Data.bwrk_gmap_substore1}',
            '{$Data.bwrk_gmap_substore2}',
            '{$Data.bwrk_gmap_substore3}',
            '{$Data.bwrk_gmap_substore4}'
        ];

        function plotMarkers() {
            for (var i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++) {

                codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);

            }
        }


        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        latlang = geocoder.geocode({
            'address': '{$Data.bwrk_gmap_mainstore}'
        }, function (results, status) {

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: primarymoem,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);



            markersArray.push(marker);
        });


        var mapOptions = {
            {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_style}styles: styleArray, {/if}
            center: latlang,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            mapTypeControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_maptypecontrol}false{else}true{/if},
            scaleControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_scaleControl}false{else}true{/if},
            zoomControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_zoomControl}false{else}true{/if},
            panControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_panControl}false{else}true{/if},
            navigationControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_navigationControl}false{else}true{/if},
            streetViewControl: {if $Data.bwrk_gmap_streetViewControl}false{else}true{/if}
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        plotMarkers();

        function codeAddresses(address) {
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            }, function (results, status) {

                if (results.length > 0) {
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: submoem,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: this.href,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajax, err) {
            console.error('error: ' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });


</script>
<style>
     #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

if the problem of the gray parts occurs only when indicating the height percentage is probably because it is not the height assigned to the tags that contain the div in which the map appears. usually are the `html` and `body` tags  or if you use the framework of the div that act as containers of the page.

Try add

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i had to add v=3 inside the google map call